# How to change numbers to text in column in R?

Tags: r

I cannot find a simple solution to my question. Yes, I am still quite new using R.

I have a factor: `w$treatment==1,2,3` in my dataset `w`

I would like text in stead of numbers when I look in my dataset, like this

`w$treatment==1` should read `Surgery`

`w$treatment==2` should read `Radiation`

`w$treatment==3` should read `Chemotherapy`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `factor`

```
w$treatment <- with(w, factor(treatment, levels = 1:3, 
                  labels = c("Surgery", "Radiation", "Chemotherapy"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is with case_when in a mutate

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

w %>%
  mutate(treatment = case_when(
                     treatment == 1 ~ "Surgery",
                     treatment == 2 ~ "Radiation",
                     treatment == 3 ~ "Chemotherapy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case you can also consider `recode()` although you may prefer `case_when()`.

It would be like this:

```
    library(tidyverse)
     library(dplyr)

w$treatment <- w$treatment %>% recode(`1`= "Surgery", `2`="Radiation", `3`= "Chemotherapy")
```